# Using CheckProperty of PersistenceSpecification on a readonly property

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Is it possible to use `.CheckProperty` when using `PersistenceSpecification` on a readonly property?

For example, a class with `Used` as a read only property, with `SetAsUsed` as a method to set the property:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Code { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime? Used { get; private set; }

    public virtual void SetAsUsed()
    {
        Used = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

I'd like to do a persistence spec, something like:

```
new PersistenceSpecification<ForgotPasswordRequest>(Session)
    .CheckProperty(x => x.Code, "a@b.com")
    .CheckProperty(x => x.Used, //??
    .VerifyTheMappings();
```

But not sure how I can invoke the `SetAsUsed` method from here?

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my  head:

```
new PersistenceSpecification<ForgotPasswordRequest>(Session)
    .CheckProperty(x => x.Code, "a@b.com")
    .CheckProperty(x => x.Used, DateTime.Now, (entity, DateTime?) => entity.SetAsUsed())
    .VerifyTheMappings();
```

Comment: With this, I get: For property 'Used' expected type 'System.DateTime' but got 'System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime,